# How to prevent SlideToggle function queue?

Tags: jquery, queue, overflow, slide

Case:
Jquery code manage a sliding EM tag (with slideToggle function) for its appearing on hover.

Problem:
The slideToggle sometimes queue the hover state.
I referred to this article:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

I tried to insert stop() function, but this not affect slideToggle();
But the methods it'going good for animate function.

This is the code where i working on:

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ProdImg a .priceTag').slideUp();    

    $('#ProdImg a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop().find('.priceTag').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#ProdImg a').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop().find('.priceTag').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="ProdImg" style=" height:240px;">
    <a title="TEXT" href="TEXT_URL" style="position:absolute; margin-left:10px;">
    <em style="text-align:right; color:#666;" class="priceTag">
        <div class="colorGoldGradient" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="rightGoldGradient" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="leftGoldGradient" style="width:100%;">
                    <div style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px;">Prezzo:<br />
                    TEXT
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </em>
    <span class="offertaTag"><span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What the crazy nested layout you develop???

Answer (score 15):

Although this is a year old now, it's always worth answering, in your example you are stopping the animation on the element **#ProdImg a**. You want to be stopping it on **.priceTag**. To do this your code should like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ProdImg a .priceTag').slideUp();        

    $('#ProdImg a').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.priceTag').stop().slideToggle();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.priceTag').stop().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Notice the **stop()** comes after the find. Meaning you are stopping the animation on this element not the parent element which has no animation running.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining why stop() has to come after find. I've been trying to figure out why my menus sometimes (but not always) stay visible after mouseout for ~3-4 weeks now. I didn't even notice that stop() was incorrectly stopping the parent.